# Combining 2 return functions

Tags: typescript

I currently have 2 functions that returns a boolean value. Both functions are doing the same check was wondering if its possible to combine both. The variable names sally and sallydocumentNo are needed to return a boolean value.

Code:

```
  const sally = (values: any) => {
    if (!values.sallyBool) {
      return {
        hidden: true,
      };
    }
  };

  const sallydocumentNo = (values: any) => {
    if (!values.sallyBool) {
      return {
        hidden: true,
      };
    }
  };
```

Comment: `const sallydocumentNo = sally` should work, but it's really unclear why you need two functions that do the same thing.  Also that `any` annotation makes this barely TypeScript.  Perhaps it should be `(values: {sallyBool: boolean}) => ...`?

Comment: Technically they return an object which has a Boolean property. What do you mean "combine"? Besides what @jcalz mentioned, you could also do `const sallydocumentNo = (values: any) => sally(values);` if, for some reason, you needed to track calls to specific functions individually.